# In which header file c++ STL hash function object is declared?

Tags: c++, hash, header

If I want to use the hash function object provided in STL, which header file I should include on Linux? e.g. hash Hf;

Comment: Do you mean a hash function ("hash function object")? Or are you referring to the hash container (hash_map in non-standard extensions, and unordered_map in the C++0X proposal)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <hash_map>
```

on some Linux distros it's available here:

```
#include <ext/hash_map>
```

More info [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash.html). The hash_map is currently not part of the official STL but it's in TR1 as `<unordered_map>`.

Comment: I know it's an extension but most C++ compilers support it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

Definition
Defined in the headers hash_map and hash_set, and in the backward-compatibility headers hash_map.h and hash_set.h. This class is an SGI extension; it is not part of the C++ standard.

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash.html